# Paypal rest sdk- internal service error has occurred error

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to execute transaction using paypal rest sdk.

I am trying in this way same as sdk documentation :.

OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential =
      new OAuthTokenCredential("", "");

```
String accessToken = tokenCredential.getAccessToken();

Address billingAddress = new Address();
billingAddress.setLine1("52 N Main ST");
billingAddress.setCity("Johnstown");
billingAddress.setCountryCode("US");
billingAddress.setPostalCode("43210");
billingAddress.setState("OH");

CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
creditCard.setNumber("4417119669820331");
creditCard.setType("visa");
creditCard.setExpireMonth("11");
creditCard.setExpireYear("2018");
creditCard.setCvv2("874");
creditCard.setFirstName("Joe");
creditCard.setLastName("Shopper");
creditCard.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);

AmountDetails amountDetails = new AmountDetails();
amountDetails.setSubtotal("7.41");
amountDetails.setTax("0.03");
amountDetails.setShipping("0.03");

Amount amount = new Amount();
amount.setTotal("7.47");
amount.setCurrency("USD");
amount.setDetails(amountDetails);

Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setAmount(amount);
transaction.setDescription("This is the payment transaction description.");

List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
transactions.add(transaction);

FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
fundingInstrument.setCreditCard(creditCard);

List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstruments = new ArrayList<FundingInstrument>();
fundingInstruments.add(fundingInstrument);

Payer payer = new Payer();
payer.setFundingInstruments(fundingInstruments);
payer.setPaymentMethod("credit_card");

Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setIntent("sale");
payment.setPayer(payer);
payment.setTransactions(transactions);

Payment createdPayment = payment.create(accessToken);

Payment executePayment = Payment.get(accessToken, "PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ");

PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
paymentExecution.setPayerId("7E7MGXCWTTKK2");

Payment newPayment = executePayment.execute(accessToken, paymentExecution);
```

But I am getting exception as

```
Caused by: com.paypal.exception.HttpErrorException: Error code : 500 with response : 
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":
"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"7a7f0k30b2719"}
        at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:108)
        at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:321)
        ... 214 more
```

Anybody can tell me why I am getting this error?

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried to execute transactions as per given in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/ rest sdk errors couple of times, but getting same exception.

Comment: FWIW i think it's a PayPal error ... i'm guessing the "sandbox" is less than stable ... i could be wrong ... however, sometimes my code works and sometimes NOT ... random ... c# .NET ... `createdInvoice = getInvoiceFromPayPal.Create(apiContext);` "A first chance exception of type 'PayPal.Exception.PayPalException' occurred in PayPalCoreSDK.dll"

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the PayPal sandbox is unfortunately not very reliable. Any of the credit cards you find on this list:  http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm 
can and will eventually return an Error 500 from PayPal.

Keep changing your test credit card numbers to avoid this problem.

You can also use your own credit card number as the sandbox environment will not charge anything to your account anyway.

I wish I had a better answer as I am also running in to this problem.

See: [PayPal Sandbox Internal Service Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413650/paypal-sandbox-internal-service-error)

Answer (score 1):

I have also found this problem.I tried to figure out this issue .After 1 hour I found that the probelm occur due to same credit card we are using multiple time. Then I register with different card,I got a new fresh token while in sandbox mode.Then my pay I got success message